# Win8 on laptop: lid turns off only the monitor

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sleep, power-management, powersave

I have an Asus S400CA with Win8. When I'm home I access it with VNC.

I'm trying to config its power settings so that, when it's plugged on AC, when I lid close it, only monitor is turned off and everything else remains on.

If I managed to config it that way, I can use it remotelly without wasting energy in its LCD.

But I can't find a way to do it. In Power Options Advanced Settings, the option Power buttons and lid > Lid close action allows me to choose only Sleep, Hibernate or Shut down. There's no option related to monitor.

Can somebody point me a way, maybe in Registry or third party software, to accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set it to "Do Nothing" all laptops should automatically turn the screen off, when lid is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the dumb question... It was just a matter of lidding it and monitor shuts down automatically. I was looking at Windows settings before acutally testing it.